# How can i print id card with magicard printer using Javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I want to print id card using java script
I used window. Print()
But it print A4 paper
Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your page:

```html
<style>
  @media print {
    @page {size: <place your size here> /*e.g: 21cm 29.7cm*/ landscape; /*other configuration here*/}
  }
</style>
```